# Using multiple frames in Tkinter is not giving the expected result

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I have been learning Tkinter, i have written a small code where i want three frames to be part of an frame. Now when i execute this code line by line, then it works as expected. However on running it as a whole program there is lot of white space between frame 1 and frame2.

```
from Tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("")
main_frame = Frame(tk)
main_frame.grid(row=0)
frame1 = Frame(main_frame, bg="blue", width=200, height=400, borderwidth =1)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2 = Frame(main_frame, bg="green", width=800, height=400)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame3 = Frame(main_frame, bg="orange", width=1000, height=100)
frame3.grid(row =1)
tk.mainloop()
```

Other problem is if i maximize the window and change it back to original size or I stretch this main window. I see frames gets overlapped and some ghost images. Can some one explain this weird behavior.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the way you're gridding it.  by default, every object gets gridded into a single block.  So, you're grid looks something like this:

```
 -------------------------------
 |    frame 1     |  frame 2   |
 -------------------------------
 |    frame 3     |  nothing   |
 -------------------------------
```

In this case, the area the `frame1` is sitting in gets expanded to accomodate `frame3` since `frame3` is so much bigger.  The workaround here is to specify the `columnspan` keyword to allow `frame3` to span more than 1 column on the grid.

```
frame3.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
```